# Redefine #define-d value

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

So I have multiple levels of `#include` going on, which eventually looks something like this:

MyHeader.h:

```
...
#include WindowsPlatform.h
...
void MyFunc()
{
    printf("File path max length: %d", PLATFORM_MAX_FILEPATH_LENGTH);
    return;
}
```

WindowsPlatform.h

```
#include minwindef.h
...
#define PLATFORM_MAX_FILEPATH_LENGTH                        MAX_PATH
...
```

minwindef.h

```
...
#define MAX_PATH          260
...
```

Note that I don't control these headers except my own.

I'm trying to override the MAX_PATH definition, apparently through a command-line parameter that looks like `-DMAX_PATH=1024` (It's part of the automated build tool thing).

However, it seems that stuff I put there isn't overriding the `#define` in the file. :/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you want other than "that won't work", which you already know.

Comment: I'm not sure you want to mess with those anyway. If you need longer path names, [consider using UNC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). UNC will give you 32K long paths.

Comment: I would use UNC, but this isn't really my code and I'm loath to change it unnecessarily. I've heavily simplified the actual layers upon layers this thing is going through.

Comment: UNC is not always the answer, however some APIs do allow the "\\?\" prefix for supporting longer paths.

Answer (score 2):

The best fix is probably to modify the header file. Try:

```
#ifndef MAX_PATH
#define MAX_PATH          260
#endif
```

If that doesn't work, something more extreme is needed, like:

```
#ifdef OVERRIDE_MAX_PATH
#define MAX_PATH OVERRIDE_MAX_PATH
#else
#define MAX_PATH          260
#endif
```

And use `-DOVERRIDE_MAX_PATH=1024`.

Comment: What if the original macro definition is already compiled into the language support library or some system library. What good changing it after the fact can possibly do?

Comment: @AnT You're making assumptions about what the OP is trying to do. The OP didn't really make their use case clear. If you want more information, why not ask them with a comment on the question?

Comment: I'm basing my assumption on the fact that macro name `MAX_PATH` matches the name of the well-known macro from WinAPI.

Answer (score 2):

Both C and C++ language specifications are deliberately designed to quietly allow "matching" macro redefinitions and complain about conflicting macro redefinitions. In both C and C++ conflicting macro definitions are "errors" (ill-formed, constraint violations - choose your term). Which means that your attempts to redefine a macro to a different value will normally trigger diagnostic messages.

If your compiler does not complain, then either your conflicting definitions never meet each other or you are doing something else incorrectly. In any case, it won't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you try to write some OS-independent code. If I understand correctly and `WindowsPlatform.h` is Windows-specific (so you already have an abstraction layer) - why you bother with overriding anything?

Why do you do this:

```
#define PLATFORM_MAX_FILEPATH_LENGTH MAX_PATH
```

and try do mess with standard definitions? Why not this way:

```
#define PLATFORM_MAX_FILEPATH_LENGTH 1024
```

If your `PLATFORM_MAX_FILEPATH_LENGTH` is defined in platform-dependent header, you can define its value differently for each platform. If you *always* want it to be `1024`, just define it in some common header.

Currently, I do not see any reason to do what you are trying to do. It is incorret anyway - you should not mess with predefined, library-wide macros, because libraries are compiled using these defined values - you can get yourself some serious trouble this way!

Comment: > Why do you do this?  Well, because it's not me that's doing it. That's just where the defines drill down to. Essentially, the platform.h and minwindef.h files are not owned by me, and I'm not going to petition the owners of the code to make a change that only got deprecated in Windows 10 build 1607 (and thus still affects everyone not on that build or higher).